# What would cause windows XP not to boot unless a mouse was present?

Tags: windows-xp, boot

This is XPe but it's virtually identical to XP.

After a BIOS update, it boots as far as the windows logo/progress bar screen. Then it halts at the black screen which follows this, and does not proceed to the pale blue screen.

If I insert a USB or PS2 mouse, it boots normally.

With the old BIOS, it boots normally.

I suspect one of the "burned in" BIOS options which you can't get at with the CMOS setup app. But I'm not sure how to get at these. It's a 2006 Phoenic Award BIOS.

Comment: I would just send a bug report to the vendor. Only they can repair the BIOS.

Comment: How long did you wait after the black screen hang?

Comment: @TheEmpireNeverEnded I inadvertently left one unit powered on overnight and the black screen was still there.

Comment: @Turbo J I've done that but the vendor isn't sure yet what the problem is. It's all getting a bit urgent so I'm looking into it as well.